# How to wrap a 'CGPoint' as an object argument passing to performSelectorInBackground?

Tags: objective-c

I am pretty new for COCOS2D and I am now trying to pass a CGPoint as an argument to a thread function. I don't know how to have it wrapped into an object. Can anyone help? thanks in advance~

Answer (score 7):

You can create an NSValue with the the CGPoint and pass that as the withObject parameter:

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1.2, 22.6)];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(someSelector:) withObject:value];
```

And then inside your selector, you can access the CGPoint in the NSValue like so:

```
CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
```

Comment: if you do this frequently it's more efficient to create a class with a single cgpoint property and re-use that class instance

Answer (score -1):

Lets say, you have have

```
CGPoint p =ccp(10,10);
```

You could wrap it into an object using pointers and malloc, something like the following :-

```
 CGPoint *wrappedP = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)); 
    wrappedP->x = p.x;     
    wrappedP->y = p.y;
```

Make sure to call

```
free(wrappedP);
```

when you are done with wrappedP so that the memory allocated for wrappedP can be released.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i am allocating memory space on the heap and getting a pointer to it as a means to reference it. Isn't this what objects are?  bergy's suggested solution of using NSValue is clearly neater but i can't understand why passing wrappedP in the thread function wont work.

Comment: The method `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` requires an argument of type `id`.  An `id` is a pointer to an instance of an `@interface`.  A pointer returned by `malloc` is not a valid `id`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

class.h:

```
-(void) method:(CGPoint )point;
```

class.m:

```
-(void) method:(CGPoint )point
{
    NSLog(@"X:%f  Y:%f",point.x,point.y);
}

// method call 

[self method:CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f)];
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [`performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-SW4) before trying to answer, since the question is about that method.